# Assigning colors to table values using Choroplethr

Tags: choroplethr

I'm trying to use choroplethr to make a map at the county level. Currently, I have 3 categorical integers (1, 2, 3) in my csv under the column value which vary depending on each county. The region column contains county fips.

I want to display the following values as the respective label , color (value = label = color):

> 0 = "None" = "white", 1 = "MD" = "#64acbe", 2 = "DO" = "#c85a5a", 3 =
>   "Both" = "#574249",

I've tried several combinations of scale_fill_brewer without the results I'm looking for. Any assistance would be great. Here's code that simulates the data I'm using:

```
library(choroplethr)
library(ggplot2)
library(choroplethrMaps)

Res <- data.frame(

region = c(45001, 22001, 51001, 16001, 19001, 21001, 29001, 40001, 8001, 19003, 16003, 17001, 18001, 28001, 38001, 31001, 39001, 42001, 53001, 55001, 50001, 72001, 72003, 72005, 72007, 72009, 45003, 27001),

value = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

county_choropleth(Res, 
            title = "All United States Medical Residencies",
            legend = "Types of Medical Residencies"
             )
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, to show the community your efforts.

Comment: Hi Dario. Thank you for using Choroplethr, and thank you for asking your question on Stack Overflow. Following up with what Ranier said. Here are great instructions for how to create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610. If you edit your existing question to be in this format, it will help the community to answer your question.

Comment: Hi all, I will figure out how to include the code I've been running. I appreciate your willingness to help.

Comment: Updated with code, hopefully this helps! Also, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for using Choroplethr.

I think that there are a few issues here. The first one I'd like to address is that your `value` column contains numeric data. This by itself is not a problem. But because you are actually using it to code categorical data (i.e. "MD", "OD", etc.) this is a problem. Therefore my first task will be to change the data type from numeric to character data:

```
> class(Res$value)
[1] "numeric"
> Res$value = as.character(Res$value)
> class(Res$value)
[1] "character"
```

Now I will replace the "numbers" with the category names that you want:

```
> Res[Res=="0"] = "None"
> Res[Res=="1"] = "MD"
> Res[Res=="2"] = "DO"
> Res[Res=="3"] = "Both"
> head(Res)
  region value
1  45001  None
2  22001    MD
3  51001    DO
4  16001  Both
5  19001  None
6  21001    MD
```

Now for the second issue. You said that you were trying to use `scale_fill_brewer`. That function is for using the Brewer scales. But you don't want those here. You say that you have your own scale. So you want to use `scale_fill_manual`.

```
county_choropleth(Res) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("None" = "#ffffffff",  
                             "MD" = "#64acbe", 
                             "DO" = "#c85a5a", 
                             "Both" = "#574249"),
                    name="Types of Medical Residencies")
```

[image]

Note: What choroplethr calls the "legend" (which is actually the *name* of the legend) is actually a property of the ggplot2 scale. In particular, it is the `name` of the scale. So if you are using your own scale, you cannot use choroplethr's `legend` parameter any more.

Of course, now we have a new problem: Alaska and Hawaii are all black. I actually forgot about this issue (it's been a while since I worked on Choroplethr). The reason this happens is very technical, and perhaps more detailed than you care for, but I will mention it here for completeness: choroplethr uses ggplot2 annotations to render AK and HI in the proper place. the `choropelthr + ggplot_scale` paradigm does not work here for AK and HI because ggplot does not propogate additional layers / scales to annotations. To get around this we must use the object-oriented features of choroplethr:

```
c = CountyChoropleth$new(Res)
c$title = "All United States Medical Residencies"
c$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_manual(values=c("None" = "#ffffffff", "MD" = "#64acbe", "DO" = "#c85a5a", "Both" = "#574249"), 
                                   name="Types of Medical Residencies")
c$render()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great and thorough answer, thank you. One thing - the legend remains "value" even after changing that section of the code. Is there anything that can be used to override this?